# How to avoid that stacked bars overlaps error bars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a stacked bar chart with error bars that sometimes dips below the top part, which hides the remaining part of the error bar. (see both blue and red for x=5 and the red for all others). I want to show the error bars entirely. I've tried various clipping options, but it didn't help with my problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetstackedplotsfive{
\makeatletter
\pgfplots@stacked@isfirstplottrue
\makeatother
\addplot [forget plot,draw=none] coordinates{(1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
X   N   Name    Activation  Inclusion   Min     Max
1   3   CR      3.73        0.85        0.50    0.23
2   3   LR      3.93        0.04        0.97    -0.13
4   5   CR      4.54        1.25        2.21    0.78
5   5   LR      4.36        0.18        0.75    0.39
7   7   CR      4.66        1.84        0.84    0.92
8   7   LR      4.82        0.32        0.51    0.53
10  9   CR      5.19        2.71        1.27    0.8
11  9   LR      5.62        0.53        0.87    0.91
13  11  CR      5.69        3.53        1.78    1.57
14  11  LR      6.00        0.71        1.16    0.71
\end{filecontents}
\def\datafile{data.csv}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ymajorgrids,
    width=.8\linewidth, height=5cm,
    ymin=0,
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=14.7pt,
    xtick={1.5,4.5,7.5,10.5,13.5},
    xticklabels={3,5,7,9,11},
]
\addplot
    [fill=blue!60!white, discard if={Name}{LR}]
    table [x=X, y=Activation] {\datafile};
\addplot
    [fill=blue!20!white, discard if={Name}{LR}]
    plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
    table [x=X, y=Inclusion, y error plus=Max, y error minus=Min] {\datafile};
\resetstackedplotsfive
\addplot
    [fill=red!60!white, discard if={Name}{CR}]
    table [x=X, y=Activation] {\datafile};
\addplot
    [fill=red!20!white, discard if={Name}{CR}]
    plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
    table [x=X, y=Inclusion, y error plus=Max, y error minus=Min] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: overlapping the error bars]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any error bars on the bottom part you can elevate the top stack to another layer above `main`, otherwise you can modify the error bars draw code by explicitly moving to another layer.

For some reason, the regular `error bar style={/pgfplots/on axis=axis foreground}` doesn't grant this elevation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    compat=1.12
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetstackedplotsfive{
\makeatletter
\pgfplots@stacked@isfirstplottrue
\makeatother
\addplot [forget plot,draw=none] coordinates{(1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
X   N   Name    Activation  Inclusion   Min     Max
1   3   CR      3.73        0.85        0.50    0.23
2   3   LR      3.93        0.04        0.97    -0.13
4   5   CR      4.54        1.25        2.21    0.78
5   5   LR      4.36        0.18        0.75    0.39
7   7   CR      4.66        1.84        0.84    0.92
8   7   LR      4.82        0.32        0.51    0.53
10  9   CR      5.19        2.71        1.27    0.8
11  9   LR      5.62        0.53        0.87    0.91
13  11  CR      5.69        3.53        1.78    1.57
14  11  LR      6.00        0.71        1.16    0.71
\end{filecontents}
\def\datafile{data.csv}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymajorgrids,
    width=.8\linewidth, height=5cm,
    ymin=0,
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=14.7pt,
    xtick={1.5,4.5,7.5,10.5,13.5},
    xticklabels={3,5,7,9,11},
]
\addplot
    [fill=blue!60!white, discard if={Name}{LR}]
    table [x=X, y=Activation] {\datafile};
\addplot
    [
    on layer=axis foreground,
    fill=blue!20!white, discard if={Name}{LR},
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
    ]
    table [x=X, y=Inclusion, y error plus=Max, y error minus=Min] {\datafile};
\resetstackedplotsfive
\addplot
    [fill=red!60!white, discard if={Name}{CR}]
    table [x=X, y=Activation] {\datafile};
\addplot
    [
    on layer=axis foreground,
    fill=red!20!white, discard if={Name}{CR},
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
    ]
    table [x=X, y=Inclusion, y error plus=Max, y error minus=Min] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]